# How do i generate a new immutable object based from a object defined with type in f#?

Tags: f#

I have this code which isn't working

```
type Option(xsdLocation:string, xmlDirectory:string) =
    member this.XsdLocation = xsdLocation 
    member this.XmlDirectory = xmlDirectory

let a1 = new Option("xsd","xml")
let a2 = {a1 with XsdLocation = "xsd2"}
```

i get the error
`error FS1129: The type 'Option' does not contain a field 'XsdLocation'`

Comment: I thought this was the way to do it, many examples online show this with other record types.  Also, i'm very new to f#, so i'm not sure of the keywords to look up this are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object you defined is a standard .NET [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/classes-%5Bfsharp%5D), not a [record](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/records-%5Bfsharp%5D).  If you want to use `with` syntax you should define it as such:

```
type Option  = {XsdLocation : string; XmlDirectory : string}

let a1 = {XsdLocation = "xsd"; XmlDirectory = "xml"}
let a2 = {a1 with XsdLocation = "xsd2"}
```

PS: I'd also recommend picking a name other than `Option` for your type since `Option` is a built-in type.

Comment: Thank you.  I did change the name i was using based on your advice.